# Order by in MySQL for multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I've four columns `sale date 4`,`sale date 3`,`sale date 2`,`sale date` in my table which are all sale dates. While displaying in page `sale date 4` is given first priority if it is not empty we are displaying it and if it is empty then comes `sale date 3` and then `sale date 2` and then `sale date`.

My problem is while sorting the results.

When is run the query with order by

```
order by 
isnull(`sale date 4`), trim(`sale date 4`) , 
isnull(`sale date 3`), trim(`sale date 3`) , 
isnull(`sale date 2`), trim(`sale date 2`) , 
isnull(`sale date`), trim(`sale date`) asc
```

I'm getting results as follows

```
**sale date 4** | **sale date 3**  | **sale date 2** | **sale date**
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-01-24      | 2013-01-24       | 2013-01-24      | 2013-01-24    
2013-01-31      | 2013-01-31       | 2013-01-31      | 2012-11-30    
2013-02-01      | 2013-02-01       | 2013-02-01      | 2013-02-01    
2013-03-08      | 2013-03-08       | 2013-03-08      | 2013-03-08    
----NULL----    | ----NULL----     | 2013-02-28      | 2012-11-02    
----NULL----    | ----NULL----     | ----NULL----    | 2013-02-28
```

And when I display in the view it will be as follows

```
1. Sale date = 2013-01-24
2. Sale date = 2013-01-31
3. Sale date = 2013-02-01
4. Sale date = 2013-03-08
5. Sale date = 2013-02-28
6. Sale date = 2013-02-28
```

But what I need is

```
1. Sale date = 2013-01-24
2. Sale date = 2013-01-31
3. Sale date = 2013-02-01
4. Sale date = 2013-02-28
5. Sale date = 2013-02-28
6. Sale date = 2013-03-08
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have spaces in column names?

Comment: Spaces in column names are actually possible in MySQL (although it's not really considered to be best practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could order by:

```
coalesce(`sale date 4`, `sale date 3`, `sale date 2`, `sale date`)
```

[COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns the first non-NULL value, eg.

```
coalesce(1,2,3,4)             returns 1
coalesce(null,2,3,4)          returns 2
...
coalesce(null,null,null,null) returns null
```

Answer (score 4):

`isnull(column)` simply returns `true` or `false`. This results in the first 4 records being the first 4 results (`true > false`) and record 5 and 6 being the last two results. The last two results are then sorted by `sale date 4` (`NULL` in both columns) up to `sale date 1`, but they remain the last two items in the ordered list.

What you want to do is probably something like this:

```
.. ORDER BY IFNULL(`sale date 4`, IFNULL(`sale date 3`,
            IFNULL(`sale date 2`, `sale date 1`)))
```

Comment: If that's what Vamsi wanted, I think COALESCE would be considerably simpler, but the spec actually calls for something slightly different - and, for me at least, unintelligble!

Comment: As I understood the question (and from what I guessed by the expected output), this is exactly what the OP wanted. Although `COALESCE` really is simpler (didn't know about that one, thank you!).

Comment: I agree this was not crystal clear from the question - but @helmbert filled well the question abstraction gaps imo :-)

Comment: OK, so why's the 4th result '2013-02-28' ?

Comment: As I understand it, records 4+5 (both 2013-02-28) of the ordered result set are records 5+6 of the input set.